# The typing of declare module does not work when trying to install .svg

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack

Installed `@svgr/webpack` connected it configured
Used this guide:
[Using svgr with webpack and TypeScript](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/issues/546)
But even he didn't help solve the problem

```
global.d.ts
declare module "*.svg" {
    import React from "react";
    export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

and typing does not work

```
ThemeSwitcher.tsx
import React from "react"
import ThemeLight from "shared/assets/icons/themeLight.svg"

const ThemeSwitcher = () => {
    return (
        <button>
            <ThemeLight NOT WORKING />
        </button>
    );
};
```

I realized that the problem is in the path of the .svg file.
When I delete the correct path to the svg file, that is, I break it.
Then declare module works, but if you don't return the correct path to svg,
then everything stops working